# box2d, how to detect collision between static and dynamic bodies

Tags: flash, actionscript, box2d, flash-builder

i am listening contact between dynamic bodies. But cannot listen contact between dynamic and static bodies .

I can handle collision detection on my b2contactListener class with this metod.

```
    public override function BeginContact(contact:b2Contact):void {
        // getting the fixtures that collided
        var fixtureA:b2Fixture=contact.GetFixtureA();
        var fixtureB:b2Fixture=contact.GetFixtureB();
        // if the fixture is a sensor, mark the parent body to be removed

        if(fixtureB.GetBody().getUniqueBodyName() == "towerBody"){
            //Towerbody is static body
                    trace("BINGOOOOOO");
                    }  

        if (fixtureA.GetBody().getUniqueBodyName() == "bomb"){
            // Bomb is dynamic body
        //  main.gamePhysics.destroyBodyWhenCollide(fixtureA.GetBody());

            var spr:Sprite = fixtureA.GetBody().GetUserData();
            spr.alpha = 0;
            fixtureA.GetBody().collisionDetected = true;            

        }
```

Plz help me out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a valid assumption that the static body will be fixtureB... it could be fixtureA.

Try testing this out...

```
public override function BeginContact(contact:b2Contact):void {
    // getting the fixtures that collided
    var fixtureA:b2Fixture=contact.GetFixtureA();
    var fixtureB:b2Fixture=contact.GetFixtureB();
    // if the fixture is a sensor, mark the parent body to be removed

    if(fixtureA.GetBody().getUniqueBodyName() == "towerBody"){
        //Towerbody is static body
                trace("BINGOOOOOO - A");
                }  

    if(fixtureB.GetBody().getUniqueBodyName() == "towerBody"){
        //Towerbody is static body
                trace("BINGOOOOOO - B");
                }  


    if (fixtureA.GetBody().getUniqueBodyName() == "bomb"){
        // Bomb is dynamic body
    //  main.gamePhysics.destroyBodyWhenCollide(fixtureA.GetBody());

        var spr:Sprite = fixtureA.GetBody().GetUserData();
        spr.alpha = 0;
        fixtureA.GetBody().collisionDetected = true;            

    }
```